# How to return data from forkJoin as non-Observable tuple?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that I can't get `forkJoin` to return the correct data from.

```
  public loadMatchAnalysis(clientId: string): void {    
    this.matchAnalysisService
      .getClientPolicySummary(clientId)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(clientPolicySummary => {
          const mappings$ = flatMap(clientPolicySummary.policyGroups, policyGroup => {
            return policyGroup.policies.map(policy => this.matchAnalysisService.getMappings(clientId, policy.id));
          });

          const calculations$ = flatMap(clientPolicySummary.policyGroups, policyGroup => {
            return policyGroup.policies.map(policy =>
              this.matchAnalysisService.getCalculationMethods(clientId, policy.id)
            );
          });

          return forkJoin(of(clientPolicySummary), ...mappings$, ...calculations$); //can't get this to return properly
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        ([clientPolicySummary, mappings, calculations]: [
          ClientPolicySummary,
          MatchAnalysisMapping[],
          Calculation[]
        ]) => {
          let matchAnalysis: MatchAnalysis[] = [];

          console.log('mappings', mappings);
          console.log('calculations', calculations); //this will be what 'mappings' should be

          clientPolicySummary.policyGroups.forEach(policyGroup => {
            policyGroup.policies.forEach(policy => {
              const _mappings = mappings.filter(m => m.id === policy.id);
              const _calculations = calculations.filter(c => c.id === policy.id);

              matchAnalysis.push({ policy: policy, mappings: _mappings, children: _calculations });
            });
          });

          new GetMatchAnalysisLoadedAction({ data: matchAnalysis }).dispatch();
        },
        error => {

        }
      );
  }
```

Based on the input of my `forkJoin`, I'm trying to return the data as a tuple for the parameter in the `subscribe()`. If I use the spread operator on `mappings$` or `calculations$`, then the data returned will be whichever comes first that uses the operator. That makes me think I shouldn't be using the spread operator here--but I'm not sure what else to do to return the data and access it as non-Observable data.

Answer (score 0):

forkJoin is an rxjs operator, all these operators handle async data flows. So you have to return an Observable, the Observable is the wrapper for async data.

as for returning a tuple, the entire tuple must be an observable. But switchmap wraps the value in a new observable so of should not be neccessary.

you could return this and type it as a [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_tuples.htm)

```
[clientPolicySummary, mappings$, calculations$]
```

or if you are getting a type error wrap it in an observable

```
of([clientPolicySummary, mappings$, calculations$])
```

Comment: So how do I access the data in the `subscribe()`? Returning it as a `tuple` yields type errors: `Argument of type '([clientPolicySummary, mappings, calculations]: [ClientPolicySummary, MatchAnalysisMapping[], Calculation[]]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: (ClientPolicySummary | Observable<MatchAnalysisMapping[]>[] | Observable<Calculation[]>[])[]) => void'.`

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to do:

```
return forkJoin(of(clientPolicySummary), forkJoin(...mappings$), forkJoin(...calculations$));
```

Because otherwise there's nothing collecting the mappings and calculations into their own arrays.